# how to highlight the current tab in gnome terminal?

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal

I'm using 16.04. In the gnome terminal 3.18.13, the color of all the tabs look similar and it's not easy to find quickly which tab I'm in...

Is there a way to highlight the current active tab? Thanks.